# Errors "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s), VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token MainActivity.java"

Tags: android

```
package com.example.temp_application;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    final ListView myLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myLV);
    final EditText myET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myET);

    final ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoList);

    myLV.setAdapter(aa);
}
```

I get errors:

> Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s), Syntax error on token "aa", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token   MainActivity.java

on this line

```
myLV.setAdapter(aa);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place this code *inside*  your onCreate() method:

```
final ListView myLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myLV);
final EditText myET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myET);

final ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoList);

myLV.setAdapter(aa);
```

To be clear:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // The above code goes here
}
```

Comment: No trouble, please click the checkmark in the upper right corner of this answer to mark the question as closed. Good luck learning Java and Android!

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of the variables should be done in the onCreate() method in your case

Answer (score 0):

The line in question isn't in the body of a function:

```
myLV.setAdapter(aa);
```

You'd probably want to move that line and the variable declarations into the `onCreate()` function.