# Android problems with ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Ok, so I tried solving this myself already but even though I found an answered question here on stackoverflow (namely this one [Errors "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s), VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token MainActivity.java"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239066/errors-syntax-error-on-tokens-misplaced-constructs-variabledeclaratorid-e)) I am still having problems. I have an Activity called HeadlinesActivity which is launched from MainActivity by clicking a button. I had the same problem as the one in the question I linked but I moved the ListView declaration and other related stuff into my onCreate() as suggested, and that got rid of the error in eclipse. However, now when I try to test the app on an emulator, if I try to click the headlines button Android gives a message saying that my app has stopped.
This is my code for HeadlinesActivity:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HeadlinesActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_headlines);

    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) ;
    }

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final String[] values = { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
      "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
      "Linux", "OS/2" } ;
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      R.layout.activity_headlines, R.id.textView1, values);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter) ;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_headlines, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: What's the error message in Logcat?

Comment: @AlexFlorescu: Umm, I'm a little new to android development so I'm not quite familiar with Logcat. I possibly remember something about that popping up; maybe I don't have it enabled. How do I view it?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse the LogCat opens automatically when the app crashes. Highlight the red error lines and press Ctrl+C to copy them, then paste them into your question. (Click "[edit]" below your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same layout in your Activity and in each ListView row...

- The Activity's layout should have the ListView (and anything else you want).
- The ListView rows should not have a ListView element... It should contain more basic building blocks like TextViews, ImageViews, etc

As far as the current error, I would guess that `activity_headlines.xml` does not have a ListView with the id `listView1` or a TextView with the id `textView1`. Try:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

Comment: Thanks, that has fixed it for me. :)